# How to set build description in Jenkins JobDSL?

Tags: jenkins-job-dsl

A Build Flow Plugin script can call `build.setDescription()` to set the build's description. Can something similar be done in a JobDSL script? Or would the script have to go through injecting an environment variable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Build Flow Plugin and the Job DSL Plugin are not necessarily comparable, they address different use cases. The Job DSL describe the static configuration of jobs whereas the Build Flow DSL describes a dynamic flow control of jobs.

That said, the Job DSL can configure the [Description Setter Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Description+Setter+Plugin) as a post-build action:

```
job {
  ...
  publishers {
    ...
    buildDescription('', '${BRANCH}')
  }
}
```

See the Job DSL wiki for details: https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/Job-reference#build-description-setter

To set the description of the seed job (the job with runs the Job DSL scripts), you can print something to the console log using `println` and then use the Description Setter Plugin to parse the log and set the description. Or you can use the Jenkins API from the DSL script:

```
def build = hudson.model.Executor.currentExecutor().currentExecutable
build.description = 'whatever'
```

Comment: Sorry, I should've been clearer. I want to set the build description of the JobDSL job, not the generated job's build description.